# How do I run sbt quietly?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've just begun writing Scala and I've written a small program that counts down from 10. The functionality is correct, but when I run with `sbt`, I find a little more than the expected prints:

```
06:39 $ sbt run
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/erip/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/erip/IdeaProjects/Hello/project
[info] Set current project to Hello Test #1 (in build file:/Users/erip/IdeaProjects/Hello/)
[info] Running Main 
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Apr 1, 2016 6:40:03 AM
```

The expected behavior here is clearly to only output the countdown:

```
06:39 $ sbt run
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

I've checked the help menu for sbt, but was unable to find a switch to make the output quiet. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti Since there's no accepted answer, I'll post one or you can, but the second answer seems to work.

Comment: go ahead, `sbt --error 'set showSuccess := false' run` works for me

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti I decided that I should just link it for good measure. It works for me, as well. Seems like there _should_ be an easier way, but this works for now. :)

Comment: Also, FWIW I opened [an issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2535) requesting this feature be added. Who knows if it'll be added.